# In Excel, highlight the top 10% orders by sales using conditional formatting based on other column

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYV1K.png)

```
Sample Data:

 Sales          Region
 $26.68         Atlantic
 $23.19         Atlantic
 $17.00         Atlantic
 $15.26         Atlantic
 $14.40         Atlantic
 $14.23         Atlantic
 $22,079.47     Northwest Territories
 $19,417.55     Northwest Territories
 $18,235.47     Northwest Territories
 $17,387.65     Northwest Territories
```

Within every region, highlight the top 10% orders by sales in light green fill and dark green border without using an additional column.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. Edit your question to include what you've already tried and any errors or problems you've encountered.

Answer (score 0):

Your formula would be:

```
=$A2>=AGGREGATE(16,6,$A$2:$A$11/($B$2:$B$11=$B2),0.9)
```

[image]